# control a loop in a thread class python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to create a thread class in python3. I want to control an infinite loop in one of the class function. I want to start or stop this loop in my main function outside the class. suppose this code:

```
import threading
from time import sleep
class my_thread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(my_thread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        print("stopping the thread")
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return(self._stop_event.is_set())

    def run(self):
        print("running the thread")
        print("start function startt()")
        self._stop_event.clear()
        self.startt()

    def startt(self):
        print("it is going to wait forever")
        while not self.stopped():
            #wait forever, this part is going to run again and again
            pass
        print("This line never executes")


if __name__+'__main__':
    thr=my_thread()
    thr.start()
    sleep(5)
    print("stopping the thread")
    thr.stop()
    # I cant start the thread and relative while loop again
    #thr.start()   
    print("Exiting the whole program")
```

But the problem is I can't start the thread twice, so what I want is to have two function for start and stop my while loop. I dont need to stop the thread but I need to control it. It means I want to call `stop()` and `startt()` functions for many times whenever needed in my main routine.
Thanks

Comment: You can use a `Queue` to pass a command to a thread. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904537/how-do-i-send-data-to-a-running-python-thread

Comment: @droravr thanks for the tip but I'm thinking to use of event because it is simpler, how to use `Queue` for controlling a loop inside the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, use Queue in my_thread class for manage task( method ) that complete or called by your thread

you can use LIFO Queue , Prioritry Queue ,FIFO Queue [detail](http://www.learn4master.com/programming-language/python/python-queue-for-multithreading)

second, add a class-method so you can add new method or task into the queue

add below code into your code :

```
from queue import Queue
# or
# from multiprocessing import Queue
class my_thread(threading.Thread):
    queue = Queue()

    @classmethod
    def add_task(cls,callable_task):
        cls.queue.put(callable_task)

    def startt(self):
        print("it is going to wait forever")
        while not self.stopped():
            #wait forever, this part is going to run again and again
            if not  self.queue.empty():
                  _m = self.queue.get()
                 # do what ever you want to do with _m

        print("This line never executes")
```

for stop thread

```
 Class my_thread(Threading.Thread)
     stop_event = threading.Event()

     @classmethod
     def stop_thread(cls)
         cls.stop_event.set()

     def startt(self):
         print("it is going to wait forever")
         cls = self.__class__
         while not cls.stop_event.is_set():
             #wait forever, this part is going to run again and again
             if not  self.queue.empty():
                 _m = self.queue.get()
                 # do what ever you want to do with _m

         print("This line never executes")
```

Now call for stop therad

```
  my_thread.stop_thread()
```

**Exapmle**

```
import threading
import time
class my_thread(threading.Thread):
    stop_event = threading.Event()

    @classmethod
    def stop_thread(cls):
        cls.stop_event.set()

    def run(self):
        print("running the thread")
        print("start function startt()")
        self.__class__.stop_event.clear()
        self.startt()

    def startt(self):
        print("it is going to wait forever")
        cls = self.__class__
        print cls.stop_event.is_set()
        while not cls.stop_event.is_set():
            pass

        print("This line never executes")

a = my_thread()
a.start()
time.sleep(0.5)
my_thread.stop_thread()
print "\n\n\n"
b = my_thread()
b.start()
time.sleep(0.5)
my_thread.stop_thread()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code but how can I start and stop the loop outside the class (in my main) and what is `_m`?

Comment: @MasoudR. I update my answer please check and add above code into your code and _m is object that add into queue

Comment: I used both codes, but I get the same result as mine, in my example the stop method works fine but I can't start it again, if I call `startt()` function after calling `stop()` It stuck on the loop and can't call `stop()` function again.

Comment: I can't use it because `startt(`) function never ends, it has an infinite loop inside or maybe I'm using it in a wrong way.
Can you please edit my code and put all codes to gather?

Comment: @MasoudR. you have to add time delay in the start and stop of thread and run above example with time delay and without time delay and check your printed output

Comment: Thanks finally it solved my problem, actually I needed to declare the object of my thread if I want to start it again. I used your method with mine and both codes work now. But what is the point of `Queue` in my problem?